# bootstrap dateTimePicker plugin

Tags: javascript, plugin

buenos dias tengo una duda estoy utilizando la librería bootstrap-dateTimePicker pero tengo un inconveniente que me muestra  las horas de 0 a 24 horas y no he podido cambiar el formato para que solo me muestre las 12 horas como en un reloj normal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero mostrar  de 1 a 12 como es normal mente pero no he podido?

Comment: Dime la libreria exacta que empleas, reconozco el componente pero no se a cual en específico es si puedes ponerme la página en github sería mucho mejor. Además pon el código que has utilizado para renderizarlo para basado en el darte una mejor respuesta.

Comment: puedes agregar tu codigo del `datepicker`

Answer (score 1):

con esta librería se puede responder a mi pregunta 
Material Inspired Clock Time Picker Plugin - jQuery MDTimePicker

ya que visualmente muestra las 12 horas  y la opción de seleccionar am o pm

a continuación dejo el link  para las personas interesadas en implementar un reloj lo podran encontrar aqui y son muy faciles de implementar

https://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/Time%20Picker/
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es mas facil que una persona entienda el reloj de izquierda al derecha este era mi respuesta al momento de convertir las horas

Answer (score 0):

No se que librería estarás usando, pero con [esta](https://github.com/weareoutman/clockpicker) podes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#reloj').clockpicker({
    autoclose: true,
    twelvehour: true
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clockpicker/0.0.7/jquery-clockpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clockpicker/0.0.7/jquery-clockpicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <input id="reloj" value="" data-default="22:22">
</div>
```